# How can I get hidden value from facelet?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a few hiden fields in my .xhtml page.

```
<h:inputHidden value="1" id="hidePrev"/>
.....
<h:inputHidden value="1" id="hideNext"/>
```

And I can't catch their values from my JSF bean.

```
public class FacesUtil {
public static Object getMapValue(String key) {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get(key);
}

public static void setMapValue(String key, Object value) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().put(key, value);
}

}
```

My bean code:

```
    nextFlag = (String)FacesUtil.getMapValue("hideNext");
    prevFlag = (String)FacesUtil.getMapValue("hidePrev");
```

Fields `nextFlag` and `prevFlag` are still empty. They have getter and setter methods. I'm using JSF 2.2 ver. Please, help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:inputHidden>` isn't intented to add custom request parameters to the form submit. It's intented to remember already-definied bean properties across postbacks. For adding custom request parameters, you should be using `<f:param>` in command components or "plain vanilla" `<input type="hidden">` instead.

Thus, so

```html
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="prev" value="1" />
    <f:param name="next" value="1" />
</h:commandButton>
```

or so

```html
<input type="hidden" name="prev" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="1" />
<h:commandButton ... />
```

Either way, the values are in a request scoped bean available as

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.prev}")
private String prev;

@ManagedProperty("#{param.next}")
private String next;
```

Or in a broader scoped bean as

```
String prev = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("prev");
String next = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("next");
```

Please note that you confused request parameters with application scoped attributes. This is seriously a pretty major mixup which proves that you have no idea what you're doing. I strongly recommend to take a pause and go through a basic JSF tutorial once again.

Comment: It very helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You sure about the `getApplicationMap()` part of `FaceUtil`? When I'm touching the external Context, it's to retrieve values from the request map:

```
Map<String, String> pMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
```

In your case, `pMap` should contain a key `hideNext`.

Comment: I tried:                                               Map<String, String> pMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  nextFlag = pMap.get("hideNext");
  prevFlag = pMap.get("hidePrev"); But it stand idle.

Comment: What do you mean by "idle"? Are the nextFlag and prevFlag variables still null after you get them from the map?

Comment: Odd, can you look at what's sent in the request from the browser (using a tool like Firebug)? Does the browser submit these values at all? Just poking around: are those input fields contained in a <h:form>?

Answer (score 0):

Try
     (String)context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(parameterName);
In your case 
parameterName may be nextFlag or prevFlag

Comment: It doesn't work too :( I tried   nextFlag =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("hideNext"); 
  prevFlag =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("hidePrev");

Comment: Check whether it is printing value of hidePrev or hideNext  when you render the jsf page on browser by using firebug inspect element